# cakephp paypal component?

Tags: cakephp, paypal, integration

I want to integrate PayPal simple Payment (by redirecting to PayPal and returning to our website after completion) gateway with my CakePHP website, any idea about available components or helpers?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used very successfully ( with a tweakette here or there! )

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/webtechnick/2009/08/11/paypal-ipn-instant-payment-notification-plugin-complete-with-paypalhelper